# Disable checkbox in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to disable a checkbox in my View using a Model property. However, in both the cases, the checkbox is disabled. Should I not be using "" in the following code?

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.HasList, new { disabled = (Model.CanModifyList) ? "" : "disabled" })%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have set `disabled=""` it is still classed as being disabled as the element will still have the `disabled` attribute. Without using JavaScript/JQuery you'll have to do an if statement in your View.

Bear with me as I'm used to Razor syntax, but it should be something like:

```
<%if (model.CanModifyList) { %>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.HasList)%> 
<% } else { %>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.HasList, new { disabled = "disabled" })%>
<% } %>
```

What would be even nicer is if you created your own HTML Helper (maybe an overload to `CheckBoxFor`) that returned the correct HTML dependent upon the model property, that way it saves you doing additional logic in your view :)

Comment: Yeah. I was trying to see if I could use the conditional operator and do without using the if/else.

Comment: @dotNetNewbie yeah the only way to do that would be a Html Helper :)

Answer (score 0):

@mattytommo's code can be rewritten as

```
@{
    if (model.CanModifyList) 
    { 
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.HasList)%> 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.HasList, new { disabled = "disabled" })
    }
}
```